Issue with text not appearing inside cupertinoFilledButton using flet library
I have created a CupertinoFilledButton using the flet library, but the text inside the button is not visible. Is there a solution available?
Container(
    content=CupertinoFilledButton(
        content=ft.Text("OK"),
        opacity_on_click=0.6,
        on_click=lambda e: print("clicked!"),
        alignment=ft.alignment.center,
        height=30,
    ),


Font size was changed to extremely small.
Container(
                content=CupertinoFilledButton(
                    content=ft.Text("OK", size=5),
                    opacity_on_click=0.6,
                    on_click=lambda e: print("clicked!"),
                    alignment=ft.alignment.center,
                    height=30,
                ),


Result: What looked like some of the letters were visible.
(English may be unnatural due to the use of translation tools, sorry)

Calling a function Container() by itself without context should throw an error in python. You need to tell us what errors are reported if we are to be helpful. Is Container a class of flet? Should it be instantiated thus: ft.Container()?

I have this issue too. I figured out this is because the button height is too small for your text to show. If you set the text so small, it may display but tiny and unreadable! By default, some padding is added to the inside of the button which causes your text to be hidden. You can set the padding to 0 to avoid this:
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.add(
        ft.Container(
            content=ft.CupertinoFilledButton(
                content=ft.Text("OK"),
                opacity_on_click=0.6,
                on_click=lambda e: print("clicked!"),
                alignment=ft.alignment.center,
                height=30,
                padding=0,
            )
        )
    )


ft.app(main)


